# Why is php composer.phar install is just hanging?

Tags: php, composer-php

php composer.phar install,
php composer.phar update, and 
php composer.phar self-update

They all just hang and go nowhere. I wonder why

Comment: other commands work? like `composer about`

Answer (score 1):

I had a php ide open with with debug on, and another running program was sitting at a breakpoint, roadblocking any php statement.

It's the second time it happened to me.

Comment: Is this an answer or you are adding more information to the question?

Comment: This was the answer. I am posting it because as a full time php developer, I tend to have lots of things open at once,, and I get caught by this too many times, and I assume someone else may benefit.

Comment: Those guys who closed your question are seriously crazy! :P